React 19 prerenderToNodeStream vs renderToPipeableStream with onAllReady
React 19 added new static server APIs, prerenderToNodeStream
Is there any functional difference in using prerenderToNodeStream instead of renderToPipeableStream with onAllReady?
I understand that the following code is the same functionally:
const { Suspense, createElement, use } = require('react');
const { renderToPipeableStream } = require('react-dom/server');
const { prerenderToNodeStream } = require('react-dom/static');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const H1 = ({ children }) => {
  const text = use(children);

  return createElement('h1', null, text);
};

const App = ({ title, size = 10 }) => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Hello!');
  });

  return createElement(
    'html',
    null,
    createElement('head', null, createElement('title', null, title)),
    createElement(
      'body',
      null,
      Array.from({ length: size }, (_, i) =>
        createElement(Suspense, { key: i }, createElement(H1, null, promise)),
      ),
    ),
  );
};

app.use('/prerender', async (req, res) => {
  const { prelude } = await prerenderToNodeStream(
    createElement(App, {
      title: 'prerenderToNodeStream',
      size: req.query.size,
    }),
    {
      bootstrapScripts: ['/main.js'],
    },
  );

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  prelude.pipe(res);
});

app.use('/render', async (req, res) => {
  let pipe;

  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ({ pipe } = renderToPipeableStream(
      createElement(App, {
        title: 'renderToPipeableStream',
        size: req.query.size,
      }),
      {
        bootstrapScripts: ['/main.js'],
        onAllReady: resolve,
        onShellError: reject,
      },
    ));
  });

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('App listening on http://localhost:3000/');
});


I'm not an expert on rendering react application on server. But as far as I know, there are some differences pointed out in the docs too.
To read more:

renderToPipeableStream
prerenderToNodeStream

Maybe for your use-case it just doesn't matter. maybe it does. the most obvious difference is when you use prerenderToNodeStream it waits for all of the content to be ready; but when you use renderToPipeableStream you have the ability to render as soon as data is getting loaded. I'm gonna quote from the docs:

To stream content as it loads, use a streaming server render API like renderToPipeableStream.

even when I asked chatgpt to make sure what I'm talking about it gave me a huge answer, but the summary is:

In summary, while both prerenderToNodeStream and renderToPipeableStream can achieve similar results in terms of rendering a React application on the server, prerenderToNodeStream offers a more streamlined and efficient approach, particularly for applications that leverage React's concurrent features. If you're starting a new project or looking to optimize an existing one, prerenderToNodeStream is likely the better choice for its simplicity and performance benefits.

I hope this explanation helps you to find your desired answer.
